# Swing BoxLayout horizontal scrollbar when vertical scrollbar is visible

Tags: swing, scrollbar, visibility

In the following SSCCE you see that a horizontal scrollbar appears even though it would be possible to just use a vertical scrollbar. This is just an example. I use my own LayoutManager and not BoxLayout, but if you have a solution for this, I can probably use it in my own LayoutManager.

I already tried with a custom JPanel which implements Scrollable, and then override TrackScrollableViewportWidth and return true, but didn't get what I wanted. The text then was just cut off on the right side.

Another thing, that is not that important, but still annoys me: If you increase the width of the window, the horizontal scrollbar disappears and the JTextArea also increases in width. But if you decrease the width of the window, the JTextArea does not adjust its width accordingly.

Thanks in advance. Here is the SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new MyFrame();
    }

    private MyFrame()
    {

        setTitle("Scrollbars and width");
        setSize(800, 200);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel container = new JPanel();
        final BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        container.setLayout(layout);

        final JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea();
        area1.setText("1sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf ");
        area1.setLineWrap(true);
        area1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        area1.setEditable(false);
        area1.setForeground(Color.RED);
        container.add(area1);

        final JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea();
        area2.setText("2sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf sdh jsdfk laskdf hdkf hsjdf ");
        area2.setLineWrap(true);
        area2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        area2.setEditable(false);
        area2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        container.add(area2);

        final JScrollPane scrollbox = new JScrollPane(container);

        this.getContentPane().add(scrollbox, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.getContentPane().invalidate();
        this.getContentPane().validate();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

nothing to do with BoxLayout, change to a one-column GridLayout to verify.

Reason is (most probably) the slightly weird sizing behaviour of a text area - it needs to be nudged into some internal initialization before doing the real-thing (that is sizing by the LayoutManager). Add a fake size call (somewhere during the config of the area), the exact values are irrelevant

```
  area1.setSize(1, Short.MAX_VALUE);
```